# Question about overloaded operator T() in C++ template class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have this little piece of code:

```
template<typename T>
class Test
{
public:
    //operator T() const { return toto; }
    T toto{ nullptr };
};

void function(int* a) {}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Test<int*> a;
    function(a);

    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't compile unless the line `operator T() const { return toto; }` is un-commented. This magically works, but I am not sure why (if I un-comment the line).

I do understand that if the line is commented, the type of `a` when passed to `function()` is incompatible with the expected type `int*`. So, of course, the compiler complains ... no problem.

I also understand that the operator returns the actual type of the object, therefore in this particular case the compiler is happy.

I don't understand why the operator is called in this particular case.

Is doing `function(a)` the same thing as doing `function(a())`, only the `()` are implicit?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I do of course this is what I say when the line is commented. I didn't understand what the line did but Francos Andrieux replied. Idiocy (mine) is the mother of many of my questions on Stack).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux ) Thanks., Totally overlooked. Would be happy to accept this as an answer if you formulate it that way).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`operator T() const { return toto; }` is a [user defined conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator), it is not `operator()`. It's used to define that your class is convertible to a different type.

`operator()` would look like this instead:

`void operator()() const { ... }`

In your case, you are using `int*` as `T`. If you substitute it yourself in the operator, you will see that it becomes `operator int*() const { return toto; }` which means "my class can be converted to an `int*` and the result of that conversion is evaluated as `return toto;`".

The function `function()` only accepts an `int*` as its argument. When you provide a `Test` instance, the call is only legal if there is a way to convert from `Test` to `int*`, which is why the `operator T` is required for the code to compile.